# How to ensure only your javascript can connect to your webserver

Tags: javascript, web-services, obfuscation

We are looking at converting some of out tools from .NET into HTML5 with a web service style backend.  The back end itself will be totally custom running on embedded hardware implementing WebSockets meaning we have full control.

The problem I have arises with the fact that half of the code will be written in JavaScript connecting to the back end.  Ideally we want to ensure no one else but "us" can do this.  And by us I mean that the JavaScript hosted in our pages (which are served up from the same embedded webserver).

Is it possible to prevent any third party, or more specifically any code that isn't located on our box, from calling the web service?

I have a few ideas, none foolproof with various drawbacks:

- Ensure the referrer address of each connection is that of the web server
- When the page is served up embed a "seed" into the JS that the JS uses to connect to the web server, like a temporary pass token.  Only requests with the correct seed will be serviced.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be great. I realise I may not get a foolproof system but something "near" would be acceptable.

Comment: The "referrer" is easily (trivially) spoofed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is yes, I thought I'd list it anyway though

Comment: No one can use `ajax` other than you (your domain)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to prevent is called [CSRF - Cross-site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Your second idea - requiring the client to provide a token in the request header that only your web server could have produced, is a common protection against this sort of attacks.

Comment: It's not quite CSRF, but similar yes.  What I want is to prevent someone else writing a web page (or app) that can access the web service I am using.

Comment: For this matter, web page == app == any request at all.

Answer (score 0):

You never can know *which code* or *from where* your webservice is called - you only receive a web request. Everything can be spoofed.

So, you will need some authentification system, where the client can proof its right to use the service. A "seed" that is sure not to become public will probably do.